# How to retrieve joomla article values, e.g. image_intro

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am struggling to retrieve the intro image of articles, within a custom module that echoes article titles with the selected tags.
But it seems as if $item->images doesn't recall the image info. My code is the following:

Can anyone help me?

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$images = json_decode($item->images);
?>

<?php JLoader::register('TagsHelperRoute', JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_tags/helpers/route.php'); ?>
<div class="tagsselected<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php if ($list) : ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($list as $i => $item) : ?>
        <li>
            <?php $item->route = new JHelperRoute; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->content_item_id, $item->core_alias, $item->core_catid, $item->core_language, $item->type_alias, $item->router)); ?>">

                <?php if (!empty($item->core_title)) :
                echo htmlspecialchars($item->core_title);
                endif; ?>

            </a>
          <img src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item->title); ?>" />

        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else : ?>
    <span><?php echo JText::_('MOD_TAGS_SIMILAR_NO_MATCHING_TAGS'); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show/print what $images consists of $images = json_decode($item->images);

Comment: What do you mean? You mean the values such as image_intro, image_intro_alt, etc.?

Comment: that comment was before answering. Ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get Article images in for loop

```
<?php foreach ($list as $i => $item) : 
// images for each article
$images = json_decode($item->images); ?>
    <li>
        // your code/ other stuff
       // display image
      <img src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item->title); ?>" />

    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I had done so. Well I tried sth and it worked like a charm. Actually I needed to insert the json declaration within the loop. Namely:

Comment: if you feel the answer is usefull, accept the answer so that other can know it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="tag_title_custom">
        <?php $item->route = new JHelperRoute; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->content_item_id, $item->core_alias, $item->core_catid, $item->core_language, $item->type_alias, $item->router)); ?>">

            <?php if (!empty($item->core_title)) :
                echo htmlspecialchars($item->core_title);
            endif; ?>
            <?php $images  = json_decode($item->core_images);?>
            <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro);?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>">
        </a>
    </li>
```